# Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed

Tags: laravel

I am running laravel with homestead on my Windows laptop. And I keep on getting this error, I was wondering if anyone could help me figure this out. Thank you. Do I have to download php again

> Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed
>   'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'

[image]

Comment: Add the function call line to the question. Note: the 128 specifies the block size, not the key size which is correct for AES. But you may be in for more trouble using mcrypt, is does not support the standard PKCS#7 née PKCS#5 padding, only non-standard null padding which can not be used with binary data. mcrypt is abandonware, it has not been maintained in years.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you may have two php versions running on your machine. However, after a lot go googling no one seems to have a solution to this problem that is geared for Windows users.

Answer (score 0):

The message is stating that instead of a constant `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` a string `"MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128"` is needed. See [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php).

That is exactly what the error message is stating.